Struggling to upload data onto MongoDB
I am trying to upload data onto my MongoDB Atlas database. The data are .csv files from the Kaggle Movies Dataset https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rounakbanik/the-movies-dataset. I have tried different methods, but nothing seems to work as it should.
Method 1
I first tried to upload the data using a Python text editor as follows:
from pymongo.mongo_client import MongoClient
from pymongo.server_api import ServerApi
import pandas as pd

uri = "..."
client = MongoClient(uri, server_api=ServerApi('1'))
db = client['db']

def load_csv_to_mongodb_batch(collection_name, file_path, batch_size=1000):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    data = df.to_dict(orient='records')
    collection = db[collection_name]
    
    # Insert data in batches
    for i in range(0, len(data), batch_size):
        batch = data[i:i + batch_size]
        collection.insert_many(batch)
        print(f"Inserted batch {i//batch_size + 1} into {collection_name} collection.")

datasets = {
    "Credits": "/path_to/credits.csv",
    "Keywords": "/path_to/keywords.csv",
    "Films": "/path_to/movies_metadata.csv",
}

for collection, file_path in datasets.items():
    load_csv_to_mongodb_batch(collection, file_path)

This uploads my data in the correct collections, however, some of my data in the .csv files is of the format [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id':2, 'name':'Adenture}], and these data entries get uploaded as strings instead of subdocuments (see the genres field in the screenshot), which makes querying difficult/impossible 
Method 2
I also tried to use mongoimport as follows: mongoimport --uri "..." --collection Films --drop --file /path_to/movies_metadata.csv. However, here I get the following message:
connected to: mongodb+srv://...
dropping: test.Films
Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character 'a' looking for beginning of value
0 document(s) imported successfully. 0 document(s) failed to import.

So, I establish a connection, drop the collection, but then it fails to import any of my data.
EDIT: Based on the comments I have added the keywords: --type=csv --headerlineto the prompt, which allows me to upload the data, but in this method, it is still uploading the data as strings instead of subdocuments.
Method 3
Finally, I even tried to convert my csv files to JSON files by putting double quotations around all keys and values. Here I converted the data as follows and then saved it as json files:
def preprocess_columns(field):
    if isinstance(field, str) and field.startswith('[') and field.endswith(']'): # deals with JSON lists
        field = field.replace("'", '"') # Replace single quotes with double quotes
        field = re.sub(r'(\b\w+\b):', r'"\1":', field) # Add double quotes around keys if missing
        return field
    elif isinstance(field, str) and field.startswith('{') and field.endswith('}'): # deals with JSON dictionaries
        field = field.replace("'", '"') 
        field = re.sub(r'(\b\w+\b):', r'"\1":', field) 
        return field
    elif isinstance(field, (int, float, bool)): # if single boolean or number --> does not need ".."
        return field
    elif not isinstance(field, (int, float, bool)): # if single string value --> need ".."
        field = field.replace('"', "'") # in case there are double quotations are part of text
        return f'"{field}"' 
    else: 
        return field

However, in this case, when using mongoimport, I get the message: 'Failed: cannot decode array into a primitive.D'
In the last method, I may have just made a mistake in converting, but I don't understand why the other two methods don't work.
I have been stuck on this for a while now, and have tried different ways, so any help would be really appreciated!
EDIT: Here are the first two films of the movies_metadata.csv file
adult,belongs_to_collection,budget,genres,homepage,id,imdb_id,original_language,original_title,overview,popularity,poster_path,production_companies,production_countries,release_date,revenue,runtime,spoken_languages,status,tagline,title,video,vote_average,vote_count
FALSE,"{'id': 10194, 'name': 'Toy Story Collection', 'poster_path': '/7G9915LfUQ2lVfwMEEhDsn3kT4B.jpg', 'backdrop_path': '/9FBwqcd9IRruEDUrTdcaafOMKUq.jpg'}",30000000,"[{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]",http://toystory.disney.com/toy-story,862,tt0114709,en,Toy Story,"Led by Woody, Andy's toys live happily in his room until Andy's birthday brings Buzz Lightyear onto the scene. Afraid of losing his place in Andy's heart, Woody plots against Buzz. But when circumstances separate Buzz and Woody from their owner, the duo eventually learns to put aside their differences.",21.946943,/rhIRbceoE9lR4veEXuwCC2wARtG.jpg,"[{'name': 'Pixar Animation Studios', 'id': 3}]","[{'iso_3166_1': 'US', 'name': 'United States of America'}]",30/10/1995,373554033,81,"[{'iso_639_1': 'en', 'name': 'English'}]",Released,,Toy Story,FALSE,7.7,5415
FALSE,,65000000,"[{'id': 12, 'name': 'Adventure'}, {'id': 14, 'name': 'Fantasy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]",,8844,tt0113497,en,Jumanji,"When siblings Judy and Peter discover an enchanted board game that opens the door to a magical world, they unwittingly invite Alan -- an adult who's been trapped inside the game for 26 years -- into their living room. Alan's only hope for freedom is to finish the game, which proves risky as all three find themselves running from giant rhinoceroses, evil monkeys and other terrifying creatures.",17.015539,/vzmL6fP7aPKNKPRTFnZmiUfciyV.jpg,"[{'name': 'TriStar Pictures', 'id': 559}, {'name': 'Teitler Film', 'id': 2550}, {'name': 'Interscope Communications', 'id': 10201}]","[{'iso_3166_1': 'US', 'name': 'United States of America'}]",15/12/1995,262797249,104,"[{'iso_639_1': 'en', 'name': 'English'}, {'iso_639_1': 'fr', 'name': 'Français'}]",Released,Roll the dice and unleash the excitement!,Jumanji,FALSE,6.9,2413

Here is the first entry of the credits.csv file (to fit within the text limit, I had to shorten the lists)
cast,crew,id
"[{'cast_id': 14, 'character': 'Woody (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f95', 'gender': 2, 'id': 31, 'name': 'Tom Hanks', 'order': 0, 'profile_path': '/pQFoyx7rp09CJTAb932F2g8Nlho.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 15, 'character': 'Buzz Lightyear (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f99', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12898, 'name': 'Tim Allen', 'order': 1, 'profile_path': '/uX2xVf6pMmPepxnvFWyBtjexzgY.jpg'}]", "[{'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f49', 'department': 'Directing', 'gender': 2, 'id': 7879, 'job': 'Director', 'name': 'John Lasseter', 'profile_path': '/7EdqiNbr4FRjIhKHyPPdFfEEEFG.jpg'}, {'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f4f', 'department': 'Writing', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12891, 'job': 'Screenplay', 'name': 'Joss Whedon', 'profile_path': '/dTiVsuaTVTeGmvkhcyJvKp2A5kr.jpg'}, {'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f55', 'department': 'Writing', 'gender': 2, 'id': 7, 'job': 'Screenplay', 'name': 'Andrew Stanton', 'profile_path': '/pvQWsu0qc8JFQhMVJkTHuexUAa1.jpg'}, {'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f5b', 'department': 'Writing', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12892, 'job': 'Screenplay', 'name': 'Joel Cohen', 'profile_path': '/dAubAiZcvKFbboWlj7oXOkZnTSu.jpg'}]", 862


Personally, I would stick with Method 1, although I'm not familiar with Pandas, as this method allows you to process the CSVs line by line. Try looping through the data and checking if the value is valid JSON and convert it.
Method 2 - Try adding --type=csv and see if that works.

Would you add several lines from the CSV to your question?

... in raw CSV pasted into a code block?

Sorry, it should be added it as raw csv now!

movies_metadata.csv is in an awkward format, seemingly a mix of typical CSV and strings of JSON.
This is rather fragile, but here's a way using csvjson (from csvkit) and jq to convert your example CSV to JSON that mongoimport should accept.
This is for a bash commandline (a different shell will probably have alternate parameter expansion/interpolation syntax):
csvjson --stream -I ./movies_metadata.csv |jq -c $'with_entries(if IN(.key;"belongs_to_collection", "genres", "production_companies", "production_countries", "spoken_languages") then .value = ((.value|gsub("\'";"\\"")? // .)|fromjson? // .) elif .key=="release_date" then .value={"$date": (.value|strptime("%d/%m/%Y")|todate)} else .value=(.value|(.|tonumber? // .=="TRUE" // if .=="FALSE" then false else . end))  end )' > ./movies_metadata.json

Assuming the format is acceptable to mongoimport, you could skip writing the JSON file and just pipe the output of the above pipe into mongoimport.
Here's what the output of:
csvjson --stream -I ./movies_metadata.csv |jq $'with_entries(if IN(.key;"belongs_to_collection", "genres", "production_companies", "production_countries", "spoken_languages") then .value = ((.value|gsub("\'";"\\"")? // .)|fromjson? // .) elif .key=="release_date" then .value={"$date": (.value|strptime("%d/%m/%Y")|todate)} else .value=(.value|(.|tonumber? // .=="TRUE" // if .=="FALSE" then false else . end))  end )'

... looks like (note the use of "$date" for proper MongoDB date type):
{
  "adult": false,
  "belongs_to_collection": {
    "id": 10194,
    "name": "Toy Story Collection",
    "poster_path": "/7G9915LfUQ2lVfwMEEhDsn3kT4B.jpg",
    "backdrop_path": "/9FBwqcd9IRruEDUrTdcaafOMKUq.jpg"
  },
  "budget": 30000000,
  "genres": [
    {
      "id": 16,
      "name": "Animation"
    },
    {
      "id": 35,
      "name": "Comedy"
    },
    {
      "id": 10751,
      "name": "Family"
    }
  ],
  "homepage": "http://toystory.disney.com/toy-story",
  "id": 862,
  "imdb_id": "tt0114709",
  "original_language": "en",
  "original_title": "Toy Story",
  "overview": "Led by Woody, Andy's toys live happily in his room until Andy's birthday brings Buzz Lightyear onto the scene. Afraid of losing his place in Andy's heart, Woody plots against Buzz. But when circumstances separate Buzz and Woody from their owner, the duo eventually learns to put aside their differences.",
  "popularity": 21.946943,
  "poster_path": "/rhIRbceoE9lR4veEXuwCC2wARtG.jpg",
  "production_companies": [
    {
      "name": "Pixar Animation Studios",
      "id": 3
    }
  ],
  "production_countries": [
    {
      "iso_3166_1": "US",
      "name": "United States of America"
    }
  ],
  "release_date": {
    "$date": "1995-10-30T00:00:00Z"
  },
  "revenue": 373554033,
  "runtime": 81,
  "spoken_languages": [
    {
      "iso_639_1": "en",
      "name": "English"
    }
  ],
  "status": "Released",
  "tagline": null,
  "title": "Toy Story",
  "video": false,
  "vote_average": 7.7,
  "vote_count": 5415
}
{
  "adult": false,
  "belongs_to_collection": null,
  "budget": 65000000,
  "genres": [
    {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "Adventure"
    },
    {
      "id": 14,
      "name": "Fantasy"
    },
    {
      "id": 10751,
      "name": "Family"
    }
  ],
  "homepage": null,
  "id": 8844,
  "imdb_id": "tt0113497",
  "original_language": "en",
  "original_title": "Jumanji",
  "overview": "When siblings Judy and Peter discover an enchanted board game that opens the door to a magical world, they unwittingly invite Alan -- an adult who's been trapped inside the game for 26 years -- into their living room. Alan's only hope for freedom is to finish the game, which proves risky as all three find themselves running from giant rhinoceroses, evil monkeys and other terrifying creatures.",
  "popularity": 17.015539,
  "poster_path": "/vzmL6fP7aPKNKPRTFnZmiUfciyV.jpg",
  "production_companies": [
    {
      "name": "TriStar Pictures",
      "id": 559
    },
    {
      "name": "Teitler Film",
      "id": 2550
    },
    {
      "name": "Interscope Communications",
      "id": 10201
    }
  ],
  "production_countries": [
    {
      "iso_3166_1": "US",
      "name": "United States of America"
    }
  ],
  "release_date": {
    "$date": "1995-12-15T00:00:00Z"
  },
  "revenue": 262797249,
  "runtime": 104,
  "spoken_languages": [
    {
      "iso_639_1": "en",
      "name": "English"
    },
    {
      "iso_639_1": "fr",
      "name": "Français"
    }
  ],
  "status": "Released",
  "tagline": "Roll the dice and unleash the excitement!",
  "title": "Jumanji",
  "video": false,
  "vote_average": 6.9,
  "vote_count": 2413
}


Thanks! That works great! I am now trying to do the same thing with another csv file from the Kaggle dataset: credits.csv (I have pasted csv code from this file in my original post), but this approach does not seem to work here? I changed the prompt to consider the cast and crew columns but I get the error: ValueError: Row 0 has 847 values, but Table only has 3 columns. Could you perhaps help me solve this issue too? Thanks!

@Q.Ask This might work for you (from the bash shell): csvjson -S -y0 -I --stream credits.csv |jq 'with_entries(.value = (.value|gsub("'"'"'";"\"")|fromjson))'.

You can use mongoimport to do the import with this line:
mongoimport --uri "mongodb+srv://..." --collection Films --type=csv --headerline  --drop --file movies_metadata.csv

You're just missing --type=csv --headerline that tells mongoimport to use CSV and that the 1st line contains the name of the fields.

Thank you for your answer, this is very helpful! I can now upload the data, but I still have the problem of data being uploaded as strings instead of subdocuments.

Try an aggregation pipeline to change the data, then use $out to output the result to a new collection and delete the original one.

What should I change the data to? Do you know what format would allow the data to get uploaded as subdocuments?

Import the data as-is from the CSV files. This will create a Films collection. Then, using an aggregation pipeline and $addFields / $project you can remove and add the fields and get the format you like. Once you run the aggregation pipeline and the docs you're getting have the desired format, $out to a new "FilmsOK" collection. Then remove the old one, rename this new one.
